# Dynamically creating google form questions using data from a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, dynamic, google-sheets, google-forms

I've got a sheet which has the serial number, the name, and the model of a bunch of printers

eg.

> 0001, Printer 1, HP
>
> 0002, Printer 2, KM

The amount of paper and ink that each printer uses is monitored by a sheet that dumps into a separate sheet. For tracking purposes is nice to have all the information in the response as opposed to just the SN. So when the serial number is filled out in the form I'd like it to pull the name and model from the sheet and grey out all the other options or something similar.

Based on what I've found dynamic updating of the form might not be possible, in which case alternate suggestions would be appreciated. Because I want to update the data based on the first answer creating the form off the sheet wouldn't really accomplish what I wanted.

I'm just looking to see if this is possible and if so some pointers on where to start. I'm new to JavaScript and especially google apps scripts which makes things more difficult.

Comment: This is really easy to do with a dialog or webapp.

Comment: Actually, Apps Script makes things easier! I recommend you starting by taking a look at the [Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script) and [Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) Quickstarts. As @Cooper pointed out, a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) would be an interesting option.